# Recursively iterate over lists

Tags: python, recursion

I'm parsing JSON and trying to recursively create a tree based on a 'parents' key, but am struggling to get the output I expect. Here's the JSON:

```
{
    "cases": [
        {
            "name": "A",
            "parents": [
                "E",
                "B"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "B",
            "parents": [
                "C",
                "D"
            ]
        },
                {
            "name": "C",
            "parents": [
                "E"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "D",    
            "parents": [
                "E"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "E",
            "parents": [
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And here's my code:

```
import json
import copy
FILE="somefile.json"

def find_path(test_name, data, current_steps):
    tc = return_test_data(test_name, data)
    parents = tc.get('parents', [])
    if not current_steps:
        current_steps.append(test_name)
    if not parents:
        return current_steps
    else:
        temp_steps = []
        for step in parents:
            new_c_s = copy.deepcopy(current_steps)
            new_c_s.append(step)
            new_steps = find_path(step, data, new_c_s)    
            temp_steps.append(new_steps)
        return temp_steps


def return_test_data(test_name, data):
    for test in data['cases']:
        if test['name'] == test_name:
            return test

    return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = json.load(open(FILE))

    steps = find_path("A", data, [])
    print ("Steps: {}".format(steps))
```

I'm expecting to see a flat list of parents, in the order they are found:

```
Steps: ['A', 'E', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'D', 'E']
```

In this case, A has two parents: E & B. Iterate over both two get their parents, so the result would be:

```
['A', 'E', {parents of E}, 'B', {parents of B}].
```

Because E has no parents, and B has parents of C and D, this (in my mind) becomes:

```
['A', 'E', 'B', 'C', {parents of C}', 'D', {parents of D}]
```

Which finally becomes:

```
['A', 'E', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'D', 'E']
```

Instead I get:

```
Steps: [['A', 'E'], [[['A', 'B', 'C', 'E']], [['A', 'B', 'D', 'E']]]]
```

I'm sure I'm passing in too much recursively, but can't figure out exactly what.

Comment: can you explain your expected output? If you want to see a flat list of elements inside `parents` in the order they appear, shouldn't your expected output be `["E", "B", "C", "D", "E", "E"]`

Comment: @ClockSlave added more info to the question to hopefully clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've made every step slightly more complicated than necessary.  I believe this generates the information you desire:

```
import json

FILE = "somefile.json"

def find_path(test_name, data):

    dictionary = return_test_data(test_name, data)

    if dictionary:
        current_steps = [test_name]

        if 'parents' in dictionary:
            for parent in dictionary['parents']:
                current_steps.extend(find_path(parent, data))

        return current_steps

    return None

def return_test_data(name, data):
    for dictionary in data['cases']:
        if dictionary['name'] == name:
            return dictionary

    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = json.load(open(FILE))

    steps = find_path("A", data)

    print("Steps:", steps)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
Steps: ['A', 'E', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'D', 'E']
>
```

Comment: This works exactly as I was hoping for. One additional question: suppose D had a parent of A - this would cause a cyclical loop. Is there an easy way of identifying that exact association? I know I can catch the recursion error, but thought it would be nice to display what the cycle was.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate on the structure like this:

#### Code:

```
parents_list = []
for record in data:
    if record['name'] not in parents_list:
        parents_list.append(record['name'])
        for p in record['parents']:
            parents_list.append(p)

print(parents_list)
```

#### Results:

```
['A', 'E', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'D', 'E']
```

Comment: I need something flexible enough to get parents for any of the data elements, for example, get a list of parents of "B"

Comment: I responded to the data you posted.

Comment: The OP provided a starting point 'A' and wanted the data constructed from that starting point by following the path/tree of parents.  Your solution simply walks the data in the order that JSON returns it -- if the data comes back in a different order, your code produces a different result, which it shouldn't.  If we add an unrelated data element (not a parent of anything in the list), it shouldn't appear in the result but your solution will include it as it ignores the path/tree aspect of the problem.